# Dividing 2 integer without using / operator using c#. Can anyone convert this to for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

Can I ask for this question to be deleted? To help me recover my account. Thank you

```
  int[] numbers = { 200, 100, 50, 3, 1 };
        int count = int.Parse(txtNumber.Text);
        double number = 0;
        double number1 = 0;
        double number2 = 0;
        double number3 = 0;
        double number4 = 0;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't Divide 0");
            return;
        }          
        while (count >= numbers[0])
        {
            count = count - numbers[0];
            number++;
        }
        txt200.Text = number.ToString();
        label1.Text = count.ToString();
        while (decimal.Parse(label1.Text) >= numbers[1])
        {
            label1.Text = (int.Parse(label1.Text) - numbers[1]).ToString();
            number1++;
        }
        txt100.Text = number1.ToString();
```

Can somebody help me to vote this for deletion??

Comment: Why not start by creating a variable for the parsed value in `label1`?

Comment: Write this as a method that takes in a number and returns a number instead of continually parsing a string and then calling `ToString` on the resulting number...

Comment: place above your code `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { ` and after your code `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an empty `for` loop, where all the operations occur in the loop's condition and the iterator:

```
int result = 1;
for (int numCopy = numerator; numCopy > denominator; numCopy -= denominator, result++);
```

Here's a sample method:

```
public static int Divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (; numerator >= denominator; numerator -= denominator, result++) ;
    return result;
}
```

Note that I'm working only with integers here. Converting strings to integers and then back to strings again inside a loop is not very efficient. Now we can convert the `Text` properties once, pass the integers to our method, and then convert the result once.

Here's a sample usage (using a Console application):

```
static void Main()
{
    int numerator = GetIntFromUser("Please enter the numerator: ");
    int denominator = GetIntFromUser("Please enter the denominator: ");

    int result = Divide(numerator, denominator);

    Console.WriteLine($"{numerator} / {denominator} = {result}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Oh, and these are the helper methods I'm using:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKeyFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical while-loop looks like this:

```
// Initialize loop variable
int i = 0;
while (i < count) // Test loop condition
{
    //TODO: Do some work.

    // Increment loop variable
    i++;
}
```

The for-loop allows you to initialize, test and increment the loop variable at one spot

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    //TODO: Do some work.
}
```

But while-loops seem appropriate here. If you extract the calculation into a function, you can reuse it. This is better than copy-pasting the code to apply it to several inputs.

```
private static int Divide(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    int result = 0;
    int remainder = dividend;
    while (remainder >= divisor) {
        remainder -= divisor;
        result++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{dividend} / {divisor} = {result}, remainder = {remainder}");
    return result;
}
```

---

Don't assign the label text inside the loop, as the label will only keep the last assignment. Also, labels are not a good place to store numbers.

1. Convert all the numbers that are in labels and textboxes to integers before you start any calculation.
2. Do the calculations without referencing any UI controls.
3. Convert and assign the result of the calculations to labels and textboxes.

Mixing UI stuff and calculations makes the code unnecessarily complicated and difficult to read.

---

Give speaking names to controls and variables. Nobody knows what a textbox named `txt3`, a label named `label1` or a variable named `number2` are supposed to represent. Good names are `txtDividend`, `txtResult` or `dividend` and `result` for the respective variables.

Comment: I am trying to do like that but I dont know what to do in the quotient that I am throwing on different variable I initiated from above.

I just want to make the code looks beautiful not repeating the while loop.